# XCode 4.3 - Uninstall XCode 4.2

Tags: xcode4.2

Initially launching XCode 4.3, I was given an option to uninstall Xcode 4.2. I didn't uninstall the first time and I'm having trouble locating that option within Xcode 4.3. How do I find this option again?

Instead of doing the uninstall manually, I would like to use what Apple recommends so please no answers on doing it any other way. Thanks.

Comment: Tried reinstalling 4.3 but it's not giving me the option again. Also, Instruments is not showing me targets anymore.

Comment: Couldn't wait any longer. Just did it manually. Removed Xcode 4.3 by deleting the app folder in Applications then ran this command.
'sudo /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=all' Afterwards just reinstalled 4.3 again for a clean fresh install.

Comment: did that work, did it let you uninstall the prior installation of xcode like the first time?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Hi I found a solution to gain the option again:

1. Close Xcode
2. Go to ~/Library/Preferences
3. Open com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist
4. Search `IDEHaveOfferedXcodesToRemove` and set the Boolean value to `false`
5. Save & close
6. Now open the Xcode 4.3 again and the option will become active again

Comment: Great info; thanks! One additional note: when I opened ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist, it opened in Xcode 4.2.  I was a little concerned about making the change with *any* version of Xcode open, but it worked anyway.  I made the changes using Xcode 4.2, saved, quit Xcode 4.2, started Xcode 4.3 and everything was as desired.

Answer (score 19):

Per the [Xcode 4.3 release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/Articles/xcode_4_3.html):

> If you choose not to delete these items on the first launch of Xcode
>   4.3, you can remove the `/Developer` folder and the Install Xcode application by dragging them to the Trash at any time.

(Whew!)